# How to add a new column in a dataframe based on the value of external list?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with two columns: `col1` and `col2`.

col1 includes the `id` of my users. users is a list of names (i.e. strings). So, id=0 is equal to the name at index 0 in my users list.

I want to add a new column in my `dataframe` including the corresponding names of the `ids`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the id column only has unique values (meaning there aren't multiple rows with the same id) you can sort the dataframe by the id column then assign the list to a new column.

```
data = {'id': [2, 1, 0, 3]}    
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)

users = ['dave', 'sandy', 'will', 'arthur']

df.sort_values(by=['id'], inplace=True) 

df['user'] = users
```

Output:

```
id    user
 0    dave
 1   sandy
 2    will
 3  arthur
```

If the id column has multiple instances of the same id, you can use a lambda function:

```
data = {'id': [3, 1, 0, 3]}    
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)

users = ['dave', 'sandy', 'will', 'arthur']

df['user'] = df.apply(lambda row: users[row.id], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
id    user
 3  arthur
 1   sandy
 0    dave
 3  arthur
```

The lambda is basically saying for every row in this new column 'user', the value should be from the users list at the index given by the rows 'id' column value.

Answer (score 0):

user_list = ['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3']

Adding column to dataframe:

```
df['UserName'] = user_list
```

Comment: user_list includes more users than what it exists in the dataframe. Then, user_1 is not equals to the id=0.